# java annotation can not receive param as const array

Tags: arrays, java-annotations

first I use annotation to receive some params, String and String[], e.g.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)  
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)  
@Documented  
public @interface RedisCacheAble {  
    String value() default "";   
    String[] names() default {};  
} 

@RedisCacheAble(value="XXOO",names = {"a","b"} )
public OrderDetailPO orderTestAble(String op) {}
```

then my manager said that the value and names must use const because other place may use this values,  so I change my code like that:

```
public static final String XXOO = "xxoo";
    public static final String XOARR = {"orderCode","accountId"};
    @RedisCacheAble(value=XXOO, names = XOARR )
    public OrderDetailPO orderTestAble(String op) {  //

    }
```

unfortunately the eclipse throw a error: XOARR must initial as an Array, so it's seems annotation can not recognized a const array, any one know why?

Answer (score 0):

Because annotation attribute value must be const. But even your array is final, its conent is also changeable. So it's not annotation can't recognize `const array`, there is no `const array`.